# How can i change a bolt head to pan type?

Tags: modeling

On the left it's my bolt options/properties and the bolt it self.
On the right it's what i need to have the option Pan to change the bolt head to Pan. But i don't have this options.

The bolt is after enabled the add-on Mesh BoltFactory.

[image: Bolt]

Comment: You can only change the settings objects at the time of creation. If the menu for the options is not visible you can access it by pressing F6

Comment: If i press F6 it show me a window in the middle but its the Translate properties. I don't have the options like on the right. In the right image in the video he got print 3d and rigidbody options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the menu for the options is not visible you can access a floating window with the same options it by pressing F6

[image]

If the menu is not visible on the tool panel, then press the + sign at the bottom of the panel.

[image]

Note that **you can only set the parameters at the time of creation of the object**.

Modifications have to be done before you use any other tool. Once you made any kind of transformation (scale, move, rotate, etc, or selected another object) **there is no way to get the menu back**. At that point, the only way to change the parameters is by creating a new object.