# pannel Landscape

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Dear Blender community,

I am new in Blender, and I build the landscapes for some specific application. After creating Landscape (Shift+A, Mesh -> Landscape), I lose the panel "Landscape." Do you know how to access this panel again?

Comment: Once you use another tool or select a new object, you cannot get back the original creation parameters.

Comment: Related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84923/how-can-i-change-a-bolt-head-to-pan-type/84926#84926

Comment: Can I click on the created landscape to access its parameters?

Comment: I don't think "I lose the panel "Landscape." is really good explanation of your problem because it might be not clear what you expected that panel to do but it is your decision to edit the question

Comment: "Can I click" You can't

Comment: Amaizing note:
**Note that you can only set the parameters at the time of creation of the object.**